# ng-show based upon calculated values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and am trying to build my own project to teach myself. I am trying to show a div based upon calculated values. No luck so far. My attempt in the html is below, as well as my controller.

```
<p> Total Value: {{calculatedValue}} </p>
<p> Total Value: {{calculatedValue2}} </p>




<div ng-show= "calculatedValue2>calculatedValue1">Don't Do It</div>
<div ng-show= "calculatedValue1>calculatedValue2">Do The Trade!</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my scoping access incorrect -- do I need to make any additions in the controller or can I just use ng-show in the HTML some how?  I am having trouble visualizing where the model/view interacts here.

Here is my controller:

```
controller('TradesController', function($scope, TradesDataFactory) {

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.selectedItem1 = 0;
    $scope.selectedItem2 = 0;

    $scope.getPlayerData = function() {
        // getting this from the services.
        TradesDataFactory.getPlayerInfo().then(function(playerInfo) {
            $scope.data.playerInfo = playerInfo;
            console.log($scope.data.playerInfo);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            //console.error(error)
        })
    }


    $scope.calc = function() {
        $scope.calculatedValue = Number($scope.selectedItem1);
        if($scope.selectedItem2){
                $scope.calculatedValue = Number($scope.selectedItem1) + Number($scope.selectedItem2);

        }

    }

    $scope.calc2 = function() {
        $scope.calculatedValue2 = Number($scope.selectedItem3);
        if ($scope.selectedItem4) {

        $scope.calculatedValue2 = Number($scope.selectedItem3) + Number($scope.selectedItem4);
        };

    }

    $scope.getPlayerData();

});
```

Comment: is it always displaying or always hiding both divs? also when are you calling `calc` and `calc2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p> Total Value: {{calculatedValue1}} </p>
```

---

```
$scope.calc = function() {
        $scope.calculatedValue1 = Number($scope.selectedItem1);
        if($scope.selectedItem2){
                $scope.calculatedValue1 = Number($scope.selectedItem1) + Number($scope.selectedItem2); //scope.calculatedValue1 not scope.calculatedValue

        }

    };
```

Variable usage is not consistent calculatedValue & calculatedValue1